# Cannot remove a desktop entry

Tags: menu, lxqt

In the lxqt panel of Lubuntu, I have a wine submenu with some uninstalled games.
I don't know how to remove them because there is no such files in `/usr/share/applications`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only desktop files for all users are installed into `/usr/share/applications`.

When you are installing those games from within wine you don't have root permissions, so it can only install the desktop files under your home directory.

You can find them in `/home/`USERNAME`/.local/share/applications`, and simply delete them.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I found these files in .local/share/desktop-directories/, deleted the ones I wanted to,
then ran update-desktop-database, nothing happens, even when passing the folder's name as an argument

Comment: Those were *.directory* files which would just be ignored anyway if you delete all of the *.desktop* files that are in that menu.

Comment: I fund a wine folder in .local/share/applications that I hadn't seen. Deleted the entry, and did not have to run update-desktop-database